# Find repeated pairs comparing two files

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, grep

I have two files:

File 1:

```
A B
C D
F A
C G
```

File 2:

```
A G
C D
A C
D C
F A
```

What I want is to find all the pairs of words repeated in file 2 when comparing to file 1 and after remove those from file 2 and join the two files. In this case, the repeated pairs are:

```
C D
D C
F A
```

Note that I don't want the same pairs in reverse order. Any word can appear multiple times in the two files.

I tried this but it's not efficient and requires an extra step to remove the repetitions from file 2:

```
cat file1 | while read f1 f2; do grep "$f1 $f2\|$f2 $f1" file2; done > redundancies.txt

grep -vf redundancies.txt file2 > file2b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ grep -vFf f1 f2
A G
A C
D C
```

This reads file 2 and removes any lines that are also present in file 1. To handle the words being in either order you can replace `f1` with a [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) that prints the file with both word orderings.

```
$ grep -vFf <(cat f1; awk '{print $2,$1}' f1) f2
A G
A C
```